# Load data asynchronous

Tags: swift, asynchronous, xml-parsing

I dont't understand how it works. If I use `contentsOf: url` is everything fine, but if I try to use async method, it doesn't work. Can you explain me the logic?

And yes, I use `@Published` and `@ObservableObject`

```
    func loadData() {
    
    self.loading = true
    
    guard let url:URL = URL(string: "THERIGHTURLTOXMLFILE") else {
        print("Error on create URL to read file")
        return
    }
    /*let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let parser = XMLParser(data: data)
            parser.delegate = self
            parser.parse()
            self.loading = false
        }
    }
    task.resume()*/
    
    if let parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: url) {
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()
        self.loading = false
    }
}
```

Here is the xml example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" xmlns:anchor="https://anchor.fm/xmlns">
<channel>
    <item>
        <title><![CDATA[This is podcast Title 1]]></title>
        <enclosure url="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
        <itunes:image href="https://randomwordgenerator.com/img/picture-generator/54e4d4444251ab14f1dc8460962e33791c3ad6e04e50744172297ed2934ccc_640.jpg"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title><![CDATA[This is podcast Title 2]]></title>
        <enclosure url="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_1MG.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
        <itunes:image href="https://randomwordgenerator.com/img/picture-generator/52e5d64a4c52a514f1dc8460962e33791c3ad6e04e507440772872dc914ec7_640.jpg"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title><![CDATA[This is podcast Title 3]]></title>
        <enclosure url="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_2MG.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
        <itunes:image href="https://randomwordgenerator.com/img/picture-generator/57e8d4474a51ae14f1dc8460962e33791c3ad6e04e507440742a7ad19e49cc_640.jpg"/>
    </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Here is the mainApp and a snippet of the view:

```
@main
struct PlaygroundAppApp: App {

var radioPlayer = RadioPlayer()

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(radioPlayer)
            .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
            .colorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
}

class RadioPlayer: ObservableObject {

@ObservedObject var podcastParser = PodcastParser()

// List of podcasts
@Published var podcasts: [Podcast] = []
@Published var podcastIndex = 0

init() {
    podcastParser.loadData()
    podcasts = podcastParser.podcasts
}

}


struct ContentView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var radioPlayer: RadioPlayer
    
var body: some View {
   //View
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    let state = RadioPlayer()
    ContentView()
        .environmentObject(state)
}
}
```

Comment: you could show the type of url your are using, does not have to be exact, 
just to give an idea. For example, is it a local file, a http or https url, etc...

Comment: @workingdog it's normal rss feed as xml file. I added example to the top

Comment: Ok but is the xml file stored locally or fetched from the internet, i.e is it a file:// or a https:// url?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson fetched from the internet https://

Comment: could you put this: `print("----> xml: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))")` after the `guard let data ...` and tell us what it prints.

Comment: @workingdog it shows the content of the xml file `----> xml: Optional("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><rss xmlns:dc=\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\"`  ....

Comment: I added more snippets above

Comment: ok, so you are saying that when you use exactly the same url in `XMLParser(contentsOf: url)`
everthing works well, is that correct?

Comment: @workingdog yes, it's correct!

Comment: Does it work if you remove DispatchQueue.main.async and instead execute the code directly in the closure to URLSession?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson no, it does't work. The same error "index out of range". The View doesn't get data. :(

Comment: when you use `URLSession.shared.dataTask...` your  `func loadData()` 
also becomes an asynchronous function. You have to use it differently 
especially in the "RadioPlayer" init(). You need to wait until it has the data 
before using that data.

Comment: That is a completely different type of error that is most likely related to your view code and/or view model

Comment: `podcasts = podcastParser.podcasts`, this is the faulty code. It gets executed _before_ the asynchronous download (and parsing) has been done.